# Problema de códificação de parametros PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um autocomplete que faz conexão via ajax, mas quando eu digitava letras com acento que inclusive estão no banco de dados a consulta não retornava nada. Tanto o banco, `php.ini` e as configurações do codeigniter (`database.php`, `config.php`) estão setando utf-8, os arquivo estão salvos com UTF-8 também.

Autocompletes:

[image: Screenshot 1 autocomplete]
[image: Screenshot 2 autocomplete]

Ai resolvi testar acessando a url direta, para o método do `getLocalidadesByUf` do `controller` `Base.php`, e imprimir o parâmetro para ver como ele estava chegando, digitei *camaç*, mas quando a pagina é submetida o valor chega como `*cama%C3%A7*`

```
class Base extends CI_Controller 
{
  public function getLocalidadesByUf($uf, $nome) { 
    echo json_encode($this->uf_model->getLocalidadesByUf($uf, $nome), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot do URL no browser]

Estou bem perdido e não sei o que fazer, teria uma dica?

Comment: Isso aí vai por get? poderia colocar o código.

Comment: Se vai por REST a URL de consumo vai ficar assim mesmo o indexador tem que dar um UTF8 decode na hora da consulta... Manda o indexador..

Comment: @rray só fiz uma função que consulta os dados mesmo... e seguir a padrão de url do codeigniter...                                                               `class Base extends CI_Controller {                                                    public function getLocalidadesByUf($uf, $nome){
       echo json_encode($this->uf_model->getLocalidadesByUf($uf, $nome), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }`

Comment: @Dom tou usando o padrão do codeigniter... https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php